# xcode std::wcout with wchar_t or std::wstring!

Tags: c++, xcode, string, character-encoding

I am trying to print a wstring/wchar_t in xcode to the console but unfortunatelly it only works with basic chars (i think ascii) chars, everything else gets displayed in numbers, for instance the following:

```
std::cout << "äöüu"<< std::endl;
std::wcout << L"äöüu" << std::endl;
```

while the cout version prints "äöüu" as expected I get the following when using wchar_t:

> \344\366\374u

any ideas about how to fix this? I am using xcode 3.2.2 64 bit and gcc 4.2 with file encoding set to Unicode (UTF-8)

Thanks!

Comment: This *might* be expected behavior, as the Terminal encoding is usually UTF-8 and `std::wcout` deals with UTF-32. But note that if you compile with `clang++` (available in LLVM 2.8 and not yet distributed with Xcode), it outputs the correct text both times.

Comment: Does it happen when you redirect the output to a file or only on the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

i had a sinilar problem but with wostream/wofstream. Googled it and this was the anser:

```
tc_ofstream ofs;

if (sizeof(TCHAR) == sizeof(wchar_t))
{
    //codecvt_utf16<TCHAR> utf16; cannot make use of non-dynamic value
    locale   loc ( locale::classic() ,new codecvt_utf16<TCHAR> );
    ofs.imbue( loc );
    ofs.open( _T(".\\test.txt") ,tc_ios::binary );

    TCHAR BOM = 0xFEFF;    ofs << BOM;
    ofs << _T("UNICODE") << endl;
}
else
{
    ofs.open( _T(".\\test.txt") ,tc_ios::binary );
    ofs << _T("NON-UNICODE") << endl;
}
```

Comment: tc_ofstream is a typedef for either wofstream or ofstream (depending on UNICODE

Answer (score 0):

If you use wxWidgets, wxString handles this for you automagically, using wxConvCurrent.